# Object of type Token is not JSON serializable

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

views.py
this is my views.py. when I wanna login I get an error.

```
class AuthAPIView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        data = request.data

        username = data.get('username', None)
        password = data.get('password', None)

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                token = Token.objects.get(user=user)
                return Response(token)
            else:
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

I have created a token for each user when registering. and now when I wanna authenticate I get an error. I wanna get my Token instead.

Comment: You need to serialize `token`, or just pass the token string like `token.token` if you have a token field

Comment: tnx my friend.. I added  `token.key` and it worked well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning a `Token` model object which is not JSON serializable.
Not sure what is the structure of your `Token` model. If you just want to return a string token, then only return that and not the entire Token object. If you want to return the complete Token object, you can create a Serializer for the Token model and use that to serialize the Token object and return it.

Comment: thank you my Friend.. needed to add `token.key`